# Rails shopping cart with Redis: storing item quantity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, shopping-cart

I'd like to store a product's quantity along with its ID using Redis. Here's what I have right now:

```
  def add
    $redis.sadd current_user_cart, params[:product_id]
    redirect_to carts_show_path(current_user_cart)
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end
```

How can I store more than one value in a single key? Do I need to use a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
Redis is a key/value store. Meaning that it only has 2 columns...
One is the key and the second one is the value, which I would in your case define as a JSON over a hash.